# How to remove last X number of character from file name

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Looking for help writing a script that will remove a specific number of characters from the end of a file name. In my specific dilemma, I have dozens of files with the following format:

*1234567 XKJDFDA.pdf*

*5413874 KJDFSXZ.pdf*

... etc. etc.

I need to remove the last 7 alpha characters to leave the 7 digits standing as the file name. Through another posted question I was able to find a script that would remove the first ***X*** number of digits from the **beginning** of the file name but I'm having an incredibly difficult time modifying it to remove from the end:

`get-childitem *.pdf | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(x) }`

Any and all relevant help would be greatly appreciated.

Respectfully,

Comment: if the current names are all `stufftokeep getridofthis.pdf` then you can simply  use `.BaseName.Split(' ')[0]` to get the part before the space.

Comment: The task is incorrect. I need to remove last 7 alpha to leave 7 digits. And what if there is 9 alpha and 7 digits?

Answer (score 1):

```
$RootFolder = '\\server.domain.local\share\folder'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $RootFolder -Filter '*.pdf' | 
    Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer -eq $false } | # No folders
    ForEach-Object { 
        if ($_.Name -match '^(?<BeginningDigits>\d{7})\s.+\.pdf$' ) {
            $local:newName = "$($Matches['BeginningDigits'])$($_.Extension)"
            return Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $local:newName -PassThru
            }    
        } |
    ForEach-Object {Write-Host "New name: $($_.Name)"}
```

If file name matches "`<FilenameBegin><SevenDigits><Space><Something>.pdf<FilenameEnd>`", then rename it to "`<SevenDigits>.<KeepExtension>`". This uses Regular Expressions with Named Selection groups ( `<BeginningDigits>` is group name ). Take a note that due to RegExp usage, this is most CPU-taking algorythm, but if you have one-time run or you have little amount of files, there is no sense. Otherwise, if you have many files, I'd recommend adding `Where-Object { $_.BaseName.Length -gt 7 } |`  before `if (.. -match ..)` to filter out files shorter than 7 symbols before RegExp check to minimize CPU Usage ( string length check is less CPU consumable than RegExp ). Also you can remove `\.pdf` from RegExp to minimize CPU usage, because you already have this filter in `Get-ChildItem`

If you strictly need match "`<7digits><space><7alpha>.pdf`", you should replace RegExp expression with `'^(?<BeginningDigits>\d{7})\s[A-Z]{7}\.pdf$'`

---

```
$RootFolder = '\\server.domain.local\share\folder'
@( Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $RootFolder -Filter '*.pdf' ) | 
    Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer -eq $false } | # No folders
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName.Length -gt 7 } | # For files where basename (name without extension) have more than 7 symbols)
    ForEach-Object { 
            $local:newName =  [string]::Join('', $_.BaseName.ToCharArray()[0..6] ) 
            return Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $local:newName -PassThru
        } |
    ForEach-Object {Write-Host "New name: $($_.Name)"}
```

Alternative: Using string split-join: Rename all files, whose name without extension > 7 symbols to first 7 symbols ( not taking in account if digits or not ), keeping extension. 
This is idiotic algorythm, because Substring is faster. This just can help learning subarray selection using `[x..y]`

Please take note that we check string length > 7 before using `[x..y]` in `Where-Object { $_.BaseName.Length -gt 7 }`. Otherwise we cat hit error when name is shorter than 7 symbols and we trying to take 7th symbol.

---

```
$RootFolder = '\\server.domain.local\share\folder'
@( Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $RootFolder -Filter '*.pdf' ) | 
    Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer -eq $false }
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName.Length -gt 7 } | # For files where basename (name without extension) have more than 7 symbols)
    ForEach-Object { 
            $local:newName = $x[0].BaseName.Substring(0,7)
            return Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $local:newName -PassThru
        } |
    ForEach-Object {Write-Host "New name: $($_.Name)"}
```

Alternative: Using substring.  Rename all files, whose name without extension > 7 symbols to first 7 symbols ( not taking in account if digits or not ), keeping extension.

`.Substring(0,7)` # 0 - position of first symbol, 7 - how many symbols to take. Please take note that we check string length > 7 before using substring in `Where-Object { $_.BaseName.Length -gt 7 }`. Otherwise we cat hit error when name is shorter than 7 symbols

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler alternative to PowerShell is using Command Prompt. If your filenames are along the lines of "00001_01.jpg", "00002_01.jpg", "00003_01.jpg", you can use the following command:

`ren ?????_0.jpg ?????.jpg`

where the number of ? matches the first part of the filename that you want to keep.
You can read more about this and other Command Prompt methods of batch renaming files in Windows at [this useful website](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/batch-rename-mass-delete-files-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  edited to preserve the extension

There's another substring() method that takes 2 args, startIndex and length.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8

```
'hithere'.substring

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
string Substring(int startIndex)
string Substring(int startIndex, int length)
```

Thus, to delete a total of 8 characters from the right of the basename, including the space:

```
get-childitem *.pdf | rename-item -newname { $_.basename.substring(0, 
  $_.basename.length-8) + $_.extension } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item:        /Users/js/1234567890.pdf 
 Destination: /Users/js/12.pdf".
```

Comment: For me, this works within powershell (ie. the name change is confirmed w/in the right directory), but in the directory GUI the files still have the old name. Any idea what that's about?

Answer (score -1):

You can write a quick bash function for this.

```
function fileNameShortener() {
    mv "$1" ${1:0:4}
}
```

This will take the first Argument. which is stored in $1, and create a substring from index 0 to the index 4 characters to the left. This is then used in the move command to move the initial file to the new filename. To Further generalise:

```
function fileNameShortener2() {
    mv "$1" ${1:$2:$3}
}
```

This can be used, to give starting point, and length of the Substring as second and third function argument.

```
fileNameShortener fileName.txt 0 -5
```

This sample would remove the last 5 characters from the Filename.

Comment: But this is powershell.